# How check all rows in card?

Tags: javascript

I have something like a card / cards. I need something that every line of the card (cards) (horizontally) checked for the presence of the flip class every time the ball was generated with the number. If the entire line has a flip class, then in section winners we insert a span with the text Line $ {data-row-id} crossed in card $ {data-id} (where data-row-id is a line number, and data-id is card number) and then the generation continue. If in any one of the cards all the lines are already filled
then it should be deduced that this card wins Card X WIN, where X is the data-id of the card.

I tried doing somethink like this, but it does not work for me and I stopped at that

```
checkCell() {
    const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.row');
    rows.forEach(row => {
      let cells = row.children;
      for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        if (cells[i].classList.contains('flip')) {
          console.log(cells[i].parentElement.dataset);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

This is visualization for my problem - https://prnt.sc/ikj7rb

JsFiddle Code - https://jsfiddle.net/7ountjhg/2/

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of cards in the row with `flip` class, and compare this to the number of cards. If they're the same, all cards have the class:

```
function checkCell() {
    const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.row');
    rows.forEach(row => {
        if (row.querySelectorAll('.cell.flip').length == row.children.length) {
            // all cards have flipped
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, i will  try. Thank you!!